# Haskell zip package: How to add mimetype file as first file of the archive

Tags: file, haskell, zip, epub

I've started using this package to create a `.epub` file and I must say it has been much smoother than the javascript library I tried previously ([epub-zipper](https://github.com/msimmer/epub-zipper))

However, there is one small detail I cannot solve: the EPUB 3.2 specification [states](https://www.w3.org/publishing/epub32/epub-ocf.html#sec-zip-container-mime) that

> The first file in the OCF ZIP Container MUST be the mimetype file

And that it must not be compressed. I have achieved the "non-compressed" condition, but i don't know how to fulfill the "first file in the zip archive" condition. This is my code:

```hs
main :: IO ()
main = do
  mimetype <- mkEntrySelector "mimetype"
  createArchive "conmocion.epub" $ do
    packDirRecur Deflate (\s -> mkEntrySelector $ "META-INF/" ++ s) "./ePub/META-INF"
    packDirRecur Deflate (\s -> mkEntrySelector $ "es/" ++ s)       "./ePub/es"
    loadEntry    Store mimetype "./ePub/mimetype"
```

And I get the following error in the [epub online validator](http://validator.idpf.org/)

```
Mimetype file entry is missing or is not the first file in the archive.
```

Any idea on how to put the mimetype file as the first file in the archive?

### Edit

Code is now:

```
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-}


module Main where

import Codec.Archive.Zip
import qualified Data.Map as M



main :: IO ()
main = do
    mimetype <- mkEntrySelector "000mimetype"
    createArchive "conmocion.epub" $ contents mimetype
    createArchive "conmocion.zip"  $ contents mimetype
  where
    contents x = do
      loadEntry    Store x "./ePub/mimetype"
      packDirRecur Deflate (mkEntrySelector . ("META-INF/" ++)) "./ePub/META-INF"
      packDirRecur Deflate (mkEntrySelector . ("es/" ++)      ) "./ePub/es"
      packDirRecur Deflate (mkEntrySelector . ("assets/" ++)  ) "./ePub/assets"



test :: IO ()
test = do
  entries <- withArchive "conmocion.epub" (M.keys <$> getEntries)
  mapM_ print entries
```

and when I call the `test` function, it prints the following:

```
ghci> test
"000mimetype"
"assets\\all.css"
"es\\chapters\\c1.xhtml"
"es\\chapters\\c2.xhtml"
"es\\chapters\\c3.xhtml"
"es\\chapters\\c4.xhtml"
"es\\chapters\\c5.xhtml"
"es\\chapters\\c6.xhtml"
"es\\chapters\\c7.xhtml"
"es\\chapters\\c8.xhtml"
"es\\chapters\\c9.xhtml"
"es\\docs\\colophon.xhtml"
"es\\docs\\coverback.xhtml"
"es\\docs\\coverfront.xhtml"
"es\\docs\\epigraph.xhtml"
"es\\docs\\legal.xhtml"
"es\\docs\\nav.xhtml"
"es\\docs\\notice.xhtml"
"es\\docs\\thanks.xhtml"
"es\\es.opf"
"META-INF\\container.xml"
```

And when I extract the zip file, the `000mimetype` file can be found inside with just the `application/epub+zip` line

### Edit 2

Quoting from [EPUB Open Container Format (OCF) 3.2](https://www.w3.org/publishing/epub32/epub-ocf.html#sec-zip-container-mime)

```
4.3 OCF ZIP Container Media Type Identification
The first file in the OCF ZIP Container MUST be the mimetype file, which meets the following requirements:

The contents of the mimetype file MUST be the MIME media type [RFC2046] string application/epub+zip encoded in US-ASCII [US-ASCII].
The mimetype file MUST NOT contain any leading or trailing padding or white space.
The mimetype file MUST NOT begin with the Unicode byte order mark U+FEFF.
The mimetype file MUST NOT be compressed or encrypted, and there MUST NOT be an extra field in its ZIP header.
```

Comment: What happens when you put `loadEntry` before the first `packDirRecur`?

Comment: the epub validator returns the same error

Comment: When you unzip the file in a separate location, is the content of the mimetype file what you expect? When you list the contents of the edoc file, is the mimetype file the first one?

Comment: The mimetype file has only one line inside, `application/epub+zip` and when I list the contents of the epub file with the `withArchive` function from the Haskell package, it always prints the files in alphabetical order, regardless of whether I call loadEntry at the start of the do block or at the end

Comment: Just as a test, copy the mimefile into a file with name like `000000mimefile`, and add it at the beginning and see if it validates. If it does, then the problem may be that the zip library is re-ordering the contents when it builds the file.

Comment: I just edited the question to reflect those tests you asked me to run

Comment: Does the latest version validate as epub document?

Comment: No, it does not validate because the file must be named exactly `mimetype`

Comment: Given all of the above, are you able to construct by hand, using the `zip` program, a valid epub document? In other words, using the paths that you provided, does the resulting epub file pass validation?

Comment: At this point, I would suspect that the package itself is re-ordering the files when it adds them, although a cursory review of the source makes it seem unlikely. You will have to come up with a workaround or use a different library.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, found the solution by using the `commit` function from the package itself. However, I'm getting now another error because of an extra field of length 20 in the mimetype file. Depressing.

```
main :: IO ()
main = do
  mimetype <- mkEntrySelector "mimetype"
  createArchive "conmocion.epub" $ do
    addEntry Store "application/epub+zip" mimetype 
    commit
    packDirRecur Deflate (mkEntrySelector . ("META-INF/" ++)) "./ePub/META-INF"
    packDirRecur Deflate (mkEntrySelector . ("es/" ++)      ) "./ePub/es"
    packDirRecur Deflate (mkEntrySelector . ("assets/" ++)  ) "./ePub/assets"
```